# How to compile a Win32 program from the command line with Delphi

Tags: delphi, command-line, ide, build

as the title says, I'm trying to compile a Win32 program without the aid of an IDE, just so I can learn.  I'm using Borland Studio 2006, and my first thought was to take some files generated from a Forms application from the IDE and compile the project file... that gave me errors about expecting unit and finding object instead.  I know that's from the dfm file which holds all the settings for a form, but I don't get how the IDE deals with that file, can anyone help me understand the system better? :)

Comment: Here is some information [how-to-compile-and-run-this-delphi-code-without-installing-an-ide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986011/how-to-compile-and-run-this-delphi-code-without-installing-an-ide).

Comment: And this link will tell you [where-is-the-main-form-name-stored-in-delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617484/where-is-the-main-form-name-stored-in-delphi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out all I needed to do is compile the top level unit into a dcu, and then the project will compile :)  If anyone else is trying to do the same thing, there's some great info at the bottom of this page

http://www.codexterity.com/raw-delphi/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood correctly, you need to grasp the structure of a Delphi project and how Forms and units work together. You cannot just cherry-pick some files and expect to be able to feed them to the compiler.

You also have to set the path to the library/components/used files so that the compiler can find everything it needs, starting with the project dpr.

I would recommend that you try first to run your project from the IDE, then once it runs, you can try it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

[WANT](http://sourceforge.net/projects/want/) automates the process of building, testing, and packaging applications and libraries much like Jakarta Ant does

Answer (score 0):

You wrote in question that you are using BDS 2006. If you want to learn more recent build process in Delphi I suggest you to upgrade at least to Delphi 2007 which introduced [MS Build usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2313435/682111).

Of course MS Build acts like "wrapper" so this is not must have but nice have :-)

Comment: Hah, I didn't even know there was a newer one than 06, shows how much I know